# Need explaining on what code does

Tags: java, swing

So I have this code because I need to add photos to my JTable and so I need to make an abstract table model. However, after seeing this code I seriously have no idea what It does, but I really want to understand it. If you could please explain it to me that would be awesome! (I also have no idea what Icon.class does inside of the code). The code is the following:

```
public class TheModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private String[] columns;
    private Object[][] rows;

    public TheModel(){}

    public TheModel(Object[][] data, String[] columnName){

        this.rows = data;
        this.columns = columnName;
    }


    public Class getColumnClass(int column){
// 4 is the index of the column image
        if(column == 4){
            return Icon.class;
        }
        else{
            return getValueAt(0,column).getClass();
        }
    }


    public int getRowCount() {
     return this.rows.length;
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
     return this.columns.length;
    }


    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

    return this.rows[rowIndex][columnIndex];
    }
    public String getColumnName(int col){
        return this.columns[col];
    }


}
```

Every explanation is greatly appreciated! I know this website is mostly for help with coding problems not with explaining but I really hope you guys could make an exception .

Comment: *"I really hope you guys could make an exception"* ... no.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Damn.

Comment: I'd suggest that you approach asking questions on a problem-orientated basis. The title you have is not really displaying you have an issue, but sends a message of a poorly thought title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so I need to make an abstract table model.

No you don't. There is no reason to create a new table model.

You can just extend the `DefaultTableModel` and override the `getColumnClass(...)` method.

> (I also have no idea what Icon.class does inside of the code

That will tell the table what type of data is stored in the column so the table can use an appropriate renderer to display the data. That is you want to see an image not text.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information about the basics on how a table works.

Comment: Thank you a lot for taking your time to explain! :)